# Sudo not prompting for password Mac bash script

Tags: macos, bash, sudo

I am trying to write a script that appends a line to the /etc/hosts, which means I need sudoer privileges.  However, if I run the script from the desktop it does not prompt for a password.  I simply get permission denied.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo '131.253.13.32        www.google.com' >> /etc/hosts
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

A terminal pops up and says permission denied, but never actually prompts for the sudo password.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does sudo work on other opparations?

Comment: It does not prompt for a password.  If I do sudo ls it will run the ls command, but it doesn't run as sudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sudo doesn't apply to the redirection operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617305/why-does-shell-redirection-fail-when-using-echo-sudo). You can use either `echo | sudo tee -a` or `sudo bash -c 'echo >>'`:

```
echo 131.253.13.32 www.google.com | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
sudo bash -c 'echo 131.253.13.32 www.google.com >> /etc/hosts'
```

Comment: bash -c command not found, but the first one worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is effectively:

1. Switch to root, and run `echo`
2. Switch back to yourself and try to append the output of `sudo` onto
   `/etc/hosts`

That doesn't work because you need to be root when you're appending to `/etc/hosts`, not when you're running `echo`.

The simplest way to do this is

```
sudo bash -c "sudo echo '131.253.13.32        www.google.com' >> /etc/hosts"
```

which will run bash itself as root. However, that's not particularly safe, since you're now invoking a shell as root, which could potentially do lots of nasty stuff (in particular, it will execute the contents of the file whose name is in the environment variable BASH_ENV, if there is one. So you might prefer to do this a bit more cautiously:

```
sudo env -i bash -c "sudo echo '131.253.13.32        www.google.com' >> /etc/hosts"
```